# TimeDistributed(GlobalAveragePooling2D()) vs TimeDistributed(Flatten())

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm, flatten

For the image classification task, I first built a CNN model that gave a higher accuracy when I used GlobalAveragePooling2D() than Flatten().

Now i want to add LSTM layers to my model, TimeDistributed(Flatten()) before the LSTM layers works fine but when i replace it with  TimeDistributed(GlobalAveragePooling2D()) i got the error :

```
Input 0 of layer "global_average_pooling2d" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 7, 1280)
```

how can fix this error ?

Comment: Check the output and input shape of each layer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`GlobalAveragePooling2D()` accepts 4D tensor with the shape (batch_size, rows, cols, channels) or with the shape (batch_size, channels, rows, cols) according to [Keras](https://keras.io/api/layers/pooling_layers/global_average_pooling2d/) document.
Here, the input shape is (None, 7, 1280). So the input dimension (ndim) is 3.
But the expected shape is like input_shape = (2, 4, 5, 3) - ndim=4.
So check out the input tensor of `GlobalAveragePooling2D()`.